# Why does my AWS instance have much less memory than listed in the specs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a Cassandra cluster on a trio of EC2 i3.large instances.  When I run the linux command df, I get the following:

[image]

It says that I have 34,732,828 1K blocks in total.  That equals approximately 34 GB.  However, the AWS website lists the following specs:

[image]

Why do I only have 34 GB if the instance has a 475 GB SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance Store Volumes are not mounted by default. For `i3.large` instance type, it will be attached to the instance as device `/dev/nvme01n1`. It is the user's responsibility to format the device and mount it.

Use this command to list the attached devices

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Refer [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ssd-instance-store.html#InstanceStoreTrimSupport) on how to format and mount the device.

Comment: I used fdisk and the SSD shows up. How do I mount it?

Comment: Is there a way to have the SSD mount on bootup automatically?  I currently have to mount it every time I restart the instance.

Comment: Add the device entry to `/etc/fstab` file